# Glance and ceph hook-failed "ceph-relation chaged"

Tags: juju, ceph

I have installed glance in one machine and ceph in another machine using juju. Ceph is running on one  machine but I try to establish a relation between glance and ceph it always shows hook-failed.

I have checked the glacne log file it says the following but I can access ceph from glance machine. Moreover, I have observed the ceph.conf file I saw the mon host is specified. I dont't understand why the errors appears?

```
INFO ceph-relation-changed unable to find any monitors in conf. please specify monitors via -m monaddr or -c ceph.conf
2014-05-20 14:57:20 INFO ceph-relation-changed couldn't connect to cluster! error -2
2014-05-20 14:57:20 INFO ceph-relation-changed unable to find any monitors in conf. please specify monitors via -m monaddr or -c ceph.conf
2014-05-20 14:57:20 INFO ceph-relation-changed couldn't connect to cluster! error -2
2014-05-20 14:57:20 INFO ceph-relation-changed unable to find any monitors in conf. please specify monitors via -m monaddr or -c ceph.conf
2014-05-20 14:57:20 INFO ceph-relation-changed Error connecting to cluster: ObjectNotFound
2014-05-20 14:57:20 INFO ceph-relation-changed Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Comment: How did you configure the ceph charm? Specifically what did you set as osd-devices? See https://jujucharms.com/fullscreen/search/precise/ceph/#readme for the required configuration.